# Zend_Config_Xml get value from tag with atributes

Tags: xml, zend-framework, parsing

I have XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configdata>
<data>
<data_name lang="en">Some name4</data_name>
</data>
</configdata>
```

For parsing I use Zend_Config_Xml:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml($dir.$file,'data');
```

Then I convert data to array:

```
print_r($config->toArray());
```

But on result I don't see value from tag **data_name** I see only attribute **lang**.
How to get value from tag? Is it possible or maybe I should parse XML file use DOMXML on PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested with your code and indeed, I couldn't get 'Some name4' neither. After some reading on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.xml.html it seems you can't mix attributeds and tags that easily. So, if you with to get both the language and the name: I made this XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> <configdata>
  <data>
      <data_name>
          <name>Some name4</name>
          <lang>en</lang>
      </data_name>
  </data> </configdata>
```

When you want the value 'Some name4' only when there is a specific language, you can use this XML:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0"?> <configdata>
> <data>
>     <data_name>
>         <en>
>             <name>Some name4</name>
>         </en>
>     </data_name>
> </data> </configdata>
> ```

I think I prefer the first XML because of its generic tags.

Comment: Thanks for link, but if I am not mistaken if I used DOM, I can mix attributes with values into tag.

Comment: That's possible. Sadly I have to experience with DOMXML.

Comment: I have exp with DOMXML. Thank for answer.